# Default Attribute With random Values in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

In my laravel project, I want set a random default value for each new created record.

According of [this Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#default-attribute-values), I try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
       'access_token'
    ];

    protected $attributes = [
        'access_token' => str::uuid()
    ];
}
```

But I get error for `protected $attributes` line

```
"Constant expression contains invalid operations"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because properties cannot contain expressions that they cannot evaluate at compile time. From the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
> referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
> for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
> defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
> followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may
> include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant
> value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
> must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Another way of doing this would be through [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events). In your User model's `boot()` method, you can hook into the `Creating` event. If this method does not exist, create it.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($user) {
        $user->access_token = (string) Str::uuid();
    });
}
```

Comment: The latest best practice in Laravel is now to use `booted()` instead of `boot()` which is also nice in that `booted()` doesn't require a call to a parent boot/booted method. There's an example in the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

Answer (score 3):

```
protected $attributes = [
    'access_token' => ''
];

public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->attributes['access_token'] = Str::uuid();
}
```

In php, it is impossible to call a function from a property

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you consider adding some references?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is arising from the way in which you are calling the uuid function.

Since it is static, you will need to access it using;

```
Str::uuid()
```

And this will return an object, so in order to get a string out of it, you will have to cast the result.

```
(string) Str::uuid()
```

Therefore essentially, your attributes property should be;

```
protected $attributes = [
    'access_token' => (string) Str::uuid()
];
```

You can have a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-uuid)

Comment: No, this won't work. Class properties cannot contain expressions that cannot be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @Mozammil, You are right. I suppose I completely overlooked the obvious and it would make more sense to have this in a creating or created model event as you have proposed. Thank you.